# remove index.php from old cubecart urls redirects on magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have been through the various answers on here related to removing index.php from url's and this appears to be an unusual variation

I am migrating a system from cubecart to magento the cubecart URl's look like

```
  www.somedomain.com/index.php/test-product-for-total-web-solutions/p_1.html
```

I need to redirect this to:

```
 www.somedomain.com/test-product-for-total-web-solutions/p_1.html
```

at this point the internal core_url_rewrites that I have entered on the system should kick in and redirect to the new page

which is

```
 www.somedomain.com/test-product-for-total-web-solutions.html
```

any ideas?

Comment: Actually just solved this one by using the existing url rewrite file from creare seo and then removing the index.php from the core_url_rewrite table entry, so instead of having [link]index.php/test-product-for-total-web-solutions/p_1.html[/link] in the core_url_rewrite table request field i changed it to [link]test-product-for-total-web-solutions/p_1.html[/link] and all is good

Answer (score 0):

Actually just solved this one by using the existing url rewrite file from creare seo and then removing the index.php from the core_url_rewrite table entry, so instead of having

> index.php/test-product-for-total-web-solutions/p_1.html

in the core_url_rewrite table request field i changed it to

> test-product-for-total-web-solutions/p_1.html

and all is good, the usual index.php removal code does the rest of the work